# How to Observe data change

Tags: flutter, dart

How to observe data-change in `dart`?

Assume I have a `Map<String, String>` AND I wanna observe on it's data change.

My current code state:-

I have `StreamController` which carry `Map<String, String>` type:-
`

```
static StreamController<Map<String, String>> notificationReceive = new StreamController<Map<String, String>>();
```

And I let user call **X** method to listen on those stream, i.e:-

```
static StreamController<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> listenForNotificationReceive()  {
    _channel.invokeMapMethod("receiveCallback");
    return notificationReceive;
  }
```

Then in another place I call this function like :-

```
AnotherClass.listenForNotificationReceive().stream.listen((onData) {
  print("MAIN, received: " + onData.toString());
});
```

But it never get called.

I push data when some method get called from native side:-

```
 switch (call.method) {
      case "received":
        print("File.dart: "+  call.arguments.toString());
        notificationReceive.addStream(call.arguments);

        break;
    }
```

What I missing here?

Comment: `addStream` works just fine: `StreamController sc = StreamController();
  sc.stream.listen(print);
  sc.addStream(Stream.fromIterable([0,3,5]));`

Comment: @pskink I believe your snip will work for 1 time like mine...
My case is there is event got fired from native side which call this method repeatedly .... Is am I understand correct ?

Comment: you said: `"But it never get called."` so was it called once or never?

Comment: @pskink Sorry, When I run the application for first time only.. but it never called through this line `notificationReceive.addStream(call.arguments);`

Comment: i dont get it: how `call.arguments` could be a `Stream`? `call` is a `MethodCall` right? if so, `arguments` is `dynamic` but i doubt that `Stream` can be passed here (they can be only primitive types)

Comment: @pskink Yup, you are right, I think I have a problem with types here..

Comment: maybe you should look at `EventChannel`? the docs say: *"A named channel for communicating with platform plugins using event streams."*

Comment: @pskink Thanks, Will take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
notificationReceive.sink.add(call.arguments); // where call.arguments is the new map
```

instead of *addStream()*

Here is a good tutorial for RxDart and streams in flutter:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/reactive-programming-streams-bloc-6f0d2bd2d248

Comment: Didn't work for me. When I convert `call.arguments` to string it works just fine